# How to fit a michaelis-menten function with a random effect using the nlme package in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nls

I am working on fitting a model using the nlme package in R. `y` is a saturating function of `x`, similar in form to a michaelis-menten function where

```
y = Vm*x / (K+x)
```

I would like to parameterize this model using my data set, and control for a third variable, `z`, as a random effect. I cannot seem to implement this so far in the nlme framework. Any tips on how to do so, or how to do so in a different package, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess you should be more specific about what you tried and where exactly the problem starts.

Comment: Try `library(nlme)`, then `help(SSmicmen)`.

Comment: How does $z$ enter into the model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem. You can code a michaelis menten function and specify a random effect in the nlme function of R using the following format:

```
model<-nlme(y~Vm*x/(K+x), fixed=(Vm+K~1), random=Vm+K~1|z)
summary(model)
```

It is useful to add starting estimates that are realistic for your parameters, which you can eyeball from a plot of your data.